# SharePoint 2013 SP1 stuck on starting crawl when one of the search servers is offline

Tags: search, enterprise-search, crawl, topology

We have the following search topology shown below. We shutoff server #12.
My first question is how come the "Crawler" is still checked and how come when I try to execute a crawl on content source it gets stuck on starting. Even trying to reset the index it gets stuck.  The moment #12 server is turned back on crawling continues.

Shouldn't crawl continue to work because of the redundancy here?

[image: Search Topology]

Comment: In my case, it was due to SearchDB getting in Suspect mode. I found this in event viewer that SearchDB login was getting failed.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same - there is bug showing an incorrect status in the UI. 
When it tells you "starting" it tries to connect to one server for one minute - if that does not work it starts crawling on the 2nd server - but still shows starting in the UI. The crawl then works as expected.

You can verify this behavior with the ULS log.

Answer (score 0):

this is Crawl components are recognized and failure.
default duration of 1 hour.

this setting is here.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\15.0\Search\Global\Gathering Manager
DisableInterval

Detected failure and will continue to crawl.